# SVG gradient not working on pages other than home

Tags: svg, gruntjs, grunt-svgstore

This is quite puzzling. I am swapping over from icon fonts in favour of [svg sprites](http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) using [grunt-svgstore](https://github.com/FWeinb/grunt-svgstore).

The logo of the page has a gradient in it.

[image: the full logo]

All was working well until I moved on to dev the other pages of the site when the gradient in the logo disappeared.

[image: gradient in image missing]

The logo was created in Illustrator and once run through `grunt-svgstore` outputs the following:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-263.1675" y1="145.0012" x2="-263.1675" y2="239.8049" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 304 239.8052)">
            <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#223A9A" />
            <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#2196F3" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 418.042 94.805" id="svg-logo">
        <title>logo</title>
        <g id="logo-symbol">
            <path fill="url(#logo-gradient)" d="M81.347,0.523c-0. ..." />
        </g>
        <g id="logo-text">
            <g>
                <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M113.23,42.32l2.185-13.941H79. ..." />
            </g>
        </g>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

I am then using this svg in the following manner:

```
<a href="/" class="logo"><svg><use xlink:href="#svg-logo"></use></svg></a>
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Does your html page have a `<base>` element on it. If so that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: Brilliant Robert! Thats got it! :)